# WPF Events, declarative or handler?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, events, declarative

I'm new to WPF and looking for best practices for event handling. For example I have a grid control with 3 checkboxes in  it and I want to call the same procedure on the Check and Uncheck Events for all 3. I can do it declaratively on the grid control:

```
<Grid Name="grdChecks" CheckBox.Checked="EvaluateMe" CheckBox.Unchecked="EvaluateMe" >
```

or I can do it in the page load

```
    Dim ck As System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox
    For Each child In Me.grdChecks.Children
        If child.GetType.Name = "CheckBox" Then
            ck = DirectCast(child, System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox)
            AddHandler ck.Checked, AddressOf Me.EvaluateMe
            AddHandler ck.Unchecked, AddressOf Me.EvaluateMe
        End If
    Next
```

Is either method considered best practice or are there other considerations?

Answer (score 0):

> Is either method considered best practice or are there other considerations?

In general, I would prefer to keep the event handler declarations in the XAML, as this does make it a bit easier to follow (no need for the check for all children in the page load).  Also, if you add a CheckBox to your Window/Control/etc that *shouldn't* be subscribed to, your `Page_Load` code would cause problems.

That being said, many people would not consider either of these as "best practice", as code behind is often discouraged in WPF.  Moving the check boxes to use bound properties within a ViewModel would often be considered the best practice.

Comment: @user2336805 If you're new to WPF, I'd recommend http://reedcopsey.com/series/windows-forms-to-mvvm/  The code's in C#, but the concepts are the same, and it's an easy way to transition for WinForms and other event-based ways of thinking.

Comment: Thanks, I'm comfortable with C# and will take a look at the link later today and provide feedback

Answer (score 0):

If your event operates on the UI / UI's functionality you'll be fine declaring the event handlers in XAML.

If your event handler should manage data logic and other stuff than UI and you're working in a MVVM structure, you should use commands to bind your events to commands in the respective view model of your view  [Check the EventToCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx)

I'm not considering that declaring event handlers in XAML's code behind is a good practice because it reduces the readability that the xaml is supposed to give.

Comment: Thank you! I've seen some references to ViewModels but haven't looked into them in depth. I will do so.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who responded. Regarding 'straight' WPF vs MVVM I  think it's a question of the right tool for the job. I can see MVVM as being useful if you're targeting multiple platforms or if you're writing a framework that others will use to develop apps. 
Is it worth investing time in writing all the plumbing if you're just targeting one platform - in my case I'm starting with a Windows app. 
For now I'm taking the approach of handling UI events, eg enabling / disabling controls in the code behind but handing off business logic to a different class.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who responded. Regarding 'straight' WPF vs MVVM I think it's a question of the right tool for the job. I can see MVVM as being useful if you're targeting multiple platforms or if you're writing a framework that others will use to develop apps. Is it worth investing time in writing all the plumbing if you're just targeting one platform - in my case I'm starting with a Windows app. For now I'm taking the approach of handling UI events, eg enabling / disabling controls in the code behind but handing off business logic to a different class

Comment: I wrote my first WPF application doing most things in code-behind. That was a huge mistake.  We're now using MVVM (with a MVVM framework to make things easier), and now that we've been doing it a while we don't even need to think about it.  Like most things, it's tough to start but eventually you reach cruising speed.